# Storing Variable value in an Array to find the Average Speed

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting my speed from the gps using `location.speed()` function and the value is getting stored in `nCurrentSpeed`.
Should i store the `nCurrentSpeed` value in an Array to get the average speed when the app has stopped? How do i do it?

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    TextView dis =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.distance);
    TextView time1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "SPEEDOFONT.TTF");
    text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    text2.setTypeface(myTypeface);
    float speed,time, distance;
    if (location == null) {
        text2.setText("-.- km/h");
    } else {
        float nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed();
        speed = (float) (nCurrentSpeed * 3.6);
        text2.setText(String.format("%.2f km/h", speed));

        time =location.getTime();


        time1.setText("" +time);

        distance = speed*time;
        dis.setText(String.format("%.2f m/s", distance));
    }

}
```

Comment: Should you? I don't know. What is it you are trying to do? If, in the end, you only want to know the average speed, simply keep the average up to date all the time... `average = ( (average * (numberOfPoints - 1 )) + currentSpeed ) / numberOfPoints; `

Comment: Do you want the average for the entire trip, or do you just want the average during the last x seconds/minutes/hours?

Comment: I actually wanted an average of the speed of the entire trip, when it ends using the stop button.

Comment: it is quite simple, create 2 variables one for storing the sum of all locations and the second to store the count of total locations and then divide the first variable by the second variable to get the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be spot on to the actual (very specific) question, but you could also use [`DoubleSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html): You can create an instance of this class, then let it [`accept`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html#accept-double-) one value after the other, and finally [get the average](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html#getAverage--) without doing manual computations - and by the way, you get the computation of the minimum and maximum for free.

```
private final DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = new DoubleSummaryStatistics();

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    ...
    float speed = ...;

    stats.accept(speed);
}

void printSummary()
{
    double average = stats.getAverage();
    double min = stats.getMin();
    double max = stats.getMax();
    ...
}
```

> EDIT:

In case you don't use Java 8 yet, you can do

```
private final List<Float> speeds = new ArrayList<Float>();

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    ...
    float speed = ...;

    speeds.add(speed);
}

private float computeAverage(List<Float> values)
{
    float sum = 0;
    for (Float v : values)
    {
        sum += v;
    }
    return sum / values.size();
}

void printSummary()
{
    double average = computeAverage(speeds);
    ...
}
```

(Similar to what @AndrewTobilko originally proposed)

Comment: Beginner, Should i create a class DoubleSummaryStatistics ? and create a method accept in the DoubleSummaryStatictics ?

Comment: @SuhailParvez This class is also part of Java 8. If you don't use this yet, you can use the method that was originally proposed by Andrew Tobilko (he now deleted it - so I added a short description in my answer)

Comment: You are my hero of the day :P . Thanks a Million :)